# Excel: Format cells if it finds similar strings in cells

Tags: excel

Given the example:

```
A1: Smith, John Michael
A2: John Michael Smith
```

What is the formula if I want to format cells (let's say color the cells green) when it finds the string "Smith" in both A1 and A2?

- A1 -> list from excel file
- A2 -> list from database

I'm comparing a list of names extracted from a user database and the list of names on an Excel file to see if which ones are missing in the database.

Comment: look into the function of "SEARCH" and look into excels conditional formatting.  other functions that may help you are AND, ISNUMBER, ISERROR.  Search A1 for what you are looking for, Search A2 for what you are looking for.  IF what you are looking for is found it should return a number.  so if you find a number in both you want to return a TRUE value.  place your formula in conditional formatting and colour accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you place the word you are looking for in A4, you could use the following formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A4,A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A4,A2)),NOT(TRIM(CLEAN(A4))=""))
```

Search will look for the text entered in cell A4 and see if it can be found in A1.  If it is found it will return a number and if is not found it will return an error.

Isnumber checks to see if the search returned a number.  if search found the word entered in A4 in A1, it will return the number of the starting position and is number will then return a value of TRUE.

The process is then repeated for the text in A2.

In order to say that the text is found in both locations you need all arguments in the AND formula to be TRUE.  if any one of them is false AND will return a value of FALSE.

The final step will be to apply conditional formatting to the cells.  Use formula as your method for your conditional formula control and use the above formula in the space provided.  Set your special format for when your formula returns a true value.

Depending on how you apply your conditional formatting, you may want to use $A$4 instead of A4.  Same goes for A1 and A2.

The last logical check that was added was to make sure that if no information was entered in A4, or a space was entered in A4 that the check would colour the cells.  In other words it will only colour the cells if there is actually something to look for in A4.